# russian letters in gentoo console as '?'

Tags: bash, gentoo, fonts, character-encoding

I managed to get russian language working in my Gnome apps, but neither in the console (Alt-Shift-F2 and such) nor in the Gnome Terminal

```
valyagentoo va1en0k # locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8


valyagentoo va1en0k # cat /etc/conf.d/consolefont 
# /etc/conf.d/consolefont

# CONSOLEFONT specifies the default font that you'd like Linux to use on the
# console.  You can find a good selection of fonts in /usr/share/consolefonts;
# you shouldn't specify the trailing ".psf.gz", just the font name below.
# To use the default console font, comment out the CONSOLEFONT setting below.
# This setting is used by the /etc/init.d/consolefont script (NOTE: if you do

CONSOLEFONT="UniCyr-sans"

# CONSOLETRANSLATION is the charset map file to use.  Leave commented to use
# the default one.  Have a look in /usr/share/consoletrans for a selection of
# map files you can use.

# CONSOLETRANSLATION="8859-1_to_uni"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some of my suggestions:

- Have you enabled the `unicode` useflag? Without it `zsh` won't be compiled with Unicode support. If you're using `bash`, it should have Unicode support through libreadline. Also, `ksh` and `tcsh` don't support Unicode at all.
- It could also be your locale or font selections, but they look fine from what I can gather. Just make sure to list your locale in `/etc/locale.gen` and generate it with `locale-gen` on the command line.

Also, take a look at the [Using UTF-8 with Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/utf-8.xml) guide from the Gentoo documentation.

Comment: for `bash`, USE="net nls -afs -bashlogger -examples -mem-scramble -plugins -vanilla". I generated the locale, dont work yet. And I think I did all steps from the guide, I'll try to reboot now

Comment: As far as I know `bash` uses `sys-apps/readline`, which has Unicode support by default (no USE flag to toggle it on/off, it's always on). So I guess that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried change consolefont to another value? I had the same problem and

```
    consolefont="cyr-sun16"
```

works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ emerge terminus-font corefonts cronyx-fonts freefonts
$ nano /etc/locale.gen
<<enter this>>
ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8
$ nano  /etc/conf.d/consolefont
<<enter this>>
CONSOLEFONT="cyr-sun16"
$ nano /etc/env.d/02locale
<<enter this>>
LC_ALL=""
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"LC_ALL=""
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
$ locale-gen 
$ /etc/init.d/consolefont restart
$ env-update 
$ source /etc/profile
```